# Trying to change the form of the multiplicative inverse of $a+b\sqrt2$ into the form $c+d\sqrt2$. [Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm struggling with this problem from Serge Lang's *Basic Mathematics*

> Let $a$, $b$ be rational numbers. Prove that the multiplicative inverse of $a+b\sqrt2$ can be expressed in the form $c+d\sqrt2$, where $c$, $d$ are rational numbers.

By multiplying the denominator and numerator of $\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt2}$ by $a-b\sqrt2$ I have been able to get $\frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a^2-2b^2}$, but after that I can't figure out how to express it in the form $c+d\sqrt2$. I tried to cancel out the $a-b\sqrt2$ but that just goes back to $\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt2}$, so I end up going in circles.

Comment: $c=\frac a {a^{2}-2b^{2}}$ and $d=-\frac b {a^{2}-2b^{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c$ and $d$ are any rational numbers. You can just split your answer into two fractions. $c$ and $d$ will be rational because the set of rational numbers are closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication and division by non-zero numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a^2-2b^2}=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}+\frac{b}{2b^2-a^2}\sqrt2.$$

Can you proceed ?

Observe that $a^2 \ne 2b^2$ (Why ?)